# Form input and select values creates an URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

I have the following code which works great:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url=document.getElementById("domain").value + document.getElementById("tld").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
URL: <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain"> <input type="text" name="tld" id="tld"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

It gives me www.domain.com/google.com ('google' being domain and '.com' being tld)

BUT, I want to substitute the 'tld' input for select menu. I've tried this:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url=document.getElementById("domain").value + document.getElementById("tld").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
URL: <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain"> <select name="tld"><option value=".com">.com</option></select><input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

I get http://www.domain.com/?domain=index&tld=.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't given the select tag an id.

```
select name="tld" id="tld">
```

Comment: Wow! How did I miss that! Cheers for that!